# Override nuget package restore directory for a project in the solution

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a common project(csproj) which is referenced in solution 1, solution 2 and so on. I added packages.config to common project.

I am having problem referencing the external dependency in common project because the location of packages folder of each solution is different. Hence the reference to DLL gets broken when I go from solution 1 to solution 2.

Is there a way for nuget to create **another packages folder** inside the project(not solution) so that a project can reference its dependencies within its own directory structure while still respecting the solution nuget.config for rest of the projects in the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having a custom nuget.config in the directory for the Common Project and then having a [repository path](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) in the nuget.config set to a specific solution independent folder? That should solve your problem.

In addition, I would recommend that [you move to using project.json](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Converting-a-csproj-from-package.config-to-project.json) if you are using Visual Studio 2015. There is a common global packages folder instead of a solution specific one. The future is project.json (soon to be integrated into MSBUILD) for nuget dependency management.

Comment: Having nuget.config at project level does not help. I have following source in nuget.config in common project and nuget still install package in solution/packages.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="external\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>`